# Get last but one row for each ID

Tags: mysql

I am using query like

```
select * from audittable where a_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

For each ID its returning 5-6 records. I wanted to get the last but one record for each ID.
Can i do this in one sql statement.

Comment: do you have any created_date or some other id column? Or can you post your table script, so we could help you

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: better to create one dummy column for a_id , then write the query through that column.

Comment: in your database r u storing any date as well like `datecreated` or etc that when your entry is entered or not and show me your column structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       @rn:=if(@prv=a_id, @rn+1, 1) as rId,
       @prv:=a_id as a_id,
       ---Remaining columns
   FROM 
       audittable
   JOIN
       (SELECT @rn:=0, @prv:=0) t
   WHERE
       a_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
   ORDER BY 
       a_id, <column> desc)tmp --Replace column with the column with which you will determine it is the last record
WHERE 
   rId=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If  your database is having  `DateCreated` or any `column` in which you are saving the `DateTime` as well like when your data is inserted for a particular row then you may use query like

```
select at1.* from audittable at1 where 
datecreated in( select max(datecreated) from audittable at2
where 
at1.id = at2.id
order by datecreated desc
);
```

You may also use `LIMIT` function as well.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, you have the columns a_id and b. For each a_id you get a set of b's. Let you want
to get the latest/highest (maximum in terms of row_id, date or another naturally increasing index) one of b's

```
SELECT MAX(b), *
FROM audittable
GROUP BY a_id
```

Here *MAX* help to get the maximum *b* from each group.

Bad news that MySQL doesn't associate MAX b with other *-columns of the table. But it still can be used in case of simple table with a_id and b columns!